# Randomly select a record from Active Directory Application Mode

Tags: algorithm, directoryservices

I need a routine to randomly select records from ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode).  Any advice to get me started on this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DirectorySearcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) filter with (objectClass=user) and pick a result at random might work.   Something like ...

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

private static DirectoryEntry GetRandomUser()
{
    DirectoryEntry luckyGuy;
    var de = new DirectoryEntry(/*conn string*/);
    de.Username = /* your user */;
    de.Password = /* your pass */;
    
    // error handling and try-catch removed for clarity and brevity
    var s = new DirectorySearcher( de );
    s.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";
    var res = s.FindAll();
    
    if( res.Count > 0 )
    {
      var idex = rnd.Next(0, res.Count);
      luckyGuy = res[idex].GetDirectoryEntry();
    }
    
    return luckyGuy;
}
```

Here's [more on DirectorySearcher](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121191519/http://geekswithblogs.net/mhamilton/archive/2006/07/15/85303.aspx).

Comment: How would you randomly pick a result from the collection?